# Elevating privileges of a Java process in OS X

Tags: java, macos

Recently we've been rewriting a Java application that runs on OS X. We have to keep the application Java in order to utilize some internal libraries. The jar needs to run with root privileges. Previously we were using AppleScript to re-execute the jar with admin privs. It's a GUI app, so the AppleScript was nice since the user could double-click the jar, get a GUI request for privs and re-launch. No CLI required. Unfortunately it looks as if some of the AppleScript jars are not packaged with the OS X version of Java any more. Outside of using a third party binary, is anyone aware of anyway to elevate your privileges in Java on OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately it looks as if some of the AppleScript jars are not packaged with the OS X version of Java any more.

Even if you can't use AppleScript directly through the Java layer any more, you could use `ProcessBuilder` to execute an external [`osascript`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) process.